# How to decrypt the password that are stored in WSO2 identity Server with Salt and SHA-256

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to view the passwords that are stored in the CARBON_DB..UM_USER table.
The passwords are stored encrypted with a salt value column.
I don't want to change the encryption but want to view the password in SQL server.

If it is a One way function, How WSo2 IS able to get it used when we will call Authenticate function and validate the user name password passed in the request is a valid one?

or it would help me, how the WSO2 Is generating the UM_USER_PASSWORD column based on the UM_SALT_VALUE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I got an asignment to decrypt Password hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008158/i-got-an-asignment-to-decrypt-password-hash)

Comment: No LLJ97, if it is a one way function how WSo2 IS is able to validate the user name password is correct?

Comment: Because the hash functions are built in a way that you can check if a password hash can match a given password but you can't "de-hash" the password.

Comment: Ok, in that case how the hash is been generate in WSo2 IS? is that a Salt value+password or password+salt value or anyother combination

Comment: For that you have to read the specification of SHA256. That's too big for the comment section here.

Comment: I want to know the logic how in WSO2 IS the password is getting saved.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The below is the answer how the encryption is working,

```
//Password+Salt value

String password = "passwordb7nujixCJvoAA7AZkLfe0A==";
MessageDigest dgst = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] byteValue = dgst.digest(password.getBytes());
password = Base64.encode(byteValue);
System.out.println("password::"+password);
```

Answer (score 2):

This [1] is the code section where it compares the provided password with stored hash. By looking at this logic, you might able to understand how it happens. Check the `preparePassword()`[2] method to understand how the salted hashing happens.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.5.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java#L1242

[2] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.5.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java#L2628