# I got an asignment to decrypt Password hash?

Tags: security, sha256, password-hash

I am new to Security and was trying to learn how can I crack my own user's databases. I have user's salt, password hashes and username. The SHA-256 password hash is computed from the concatenation of 3 strings i.e. one constant string potPlantSalt, the password, and the
salt. SHA-256 output has been converted into the hexadecimal format and truncated
to 32 characters before storing into the database as a string.

truncate ( hexstring ( SHA256 ( " potPlantSalt " + password + salt ) ) )

I have data like:
username: max
password hash: 2b1ac087bd54ea9dcbfba2c3e63b2335
salt: 5aa8698c4022fe1d

How can I know above user decoded password?

Comment: You can't. The purpose of hash functions is to generate a value that can't be decoded. It's a one way function. The only possible way is to brute force the password but even that is often not successful.

Comment: Since this is an assignment, you might look at [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/)

Answer (score 3):

SHA256 is a [one way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), this means that given the output of SHA256, it is very, very difficult and time consuming to compute an input. So time consuming that it is impractical on current hardware.

So instead you have to use a [brute force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack): hash millions of potential passwords until you find one that produces the same hash as stored in the database. Note that this must not necessarily be the original password ([hash collision](https://learncryptography.com/hash-functions/hash-collision-attack)).

If we assume that the user did not use a combination of random characters, the search space can be reduced by using a [Dictionary attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack).

You can reduce computation time by using more storage space with [Rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Example).

Comment: Nit: `the input` is not correct, it should be `an input`. We cannot be sure. In the pre-image attack, we try to find a pre-image. It is not necessarily the pre-image, here that is user's password as you noted in the second paragraph.

Comment: Also, if salt is used properly, that is random for each password, this prevents the rainbow tables. And, hash collisions are not related to passwords it requires resistance to preimages.. See from [information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/86735). What you describe is finding a pre-image not hash collisions.